# How can I make a tool drop blocks with CanPlaceOn tag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Adventure mode, I'm trying to let a player get blocks that he can place later, is there a way to do it directly or do I have to change them in his inventory?

Situation: The player gets a tool that will allow him to clear a boulder blocking the road. Further down the path, he encounters a broken bridge, and I want him to use the blocks he gathered before to rebuild it.

At the moment, if I build the boulder with blocks having the `CanPlaceOn` tag, the tag disappear when the player destroys them and they go in its inventory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a execute command on all players that are holding the tool which sets the tag on all items you want the tag on:

Run these once:

```
/scoreboard objectives add holdingTool dummy
/scoreboard objectives add tagItem dummy
/scoreboard objectives add life stat.timeSinceDeath
```

Run these on a clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @a holdingTool 0
/scoreboard players set @a holdingTool 1 {SelectedItem:<Tool>}
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] tagItem 0
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item,score_life=1] tagItem 1 {Item:<Data Tags of Item>}
/execute @a[score_holdingTool_min = 1] ~ ~ ~ entitydata @e[score_tagItem_min = 1,r=5] {Item:{tag:{CanPlaceOn:["<Block That Can Be Placed On>"]}}}
```

This will run the entitydata command on all items around players in a 5 block range with the holdingTool tag of 1, aka all players who have the specific tool selected. the entitydata command will only affect items of the correct type that has just spawned.

Answer (score 1):

Use a /fill clock hooked up to three command blocks to add the tag to item entities. Unfortunately, I don't know if it's possible to limit this to only those created with a specific tool.

First, create a scoreboard objective to keep track of the items you'll be adding the tag to.

```
/scoreboard objectives add itemID dummy
```

The first command block (order of execution does matter) in the fill clock will reset the objective for all item entities currently loaded.

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] itemID 0
```

The second sets the score based upon item id. Note that you can affect different types of items by assigning different values.

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] itemID 1 {Item:{id:minecraft:stone}}
```

Lastly, add the CanPlaceOn tag to all items with the right score.

```
/entitydata @e[score_itemID_min=1,score_itemID=1] {Item:{tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

As of Minecraft 1.13, this can be done in just one command (not counting set-up):

Set-up:

```
/scoreboard objectives add life minecraft.custom:minecraft.timeSinceDeath
```

Every tick:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:<tool>}] as @e[type=item,distance=..5,nbt={Item:<Data Tags of Item>}] run data merge entity @s {Item:{tag:{CanPlaceOn:["<Block That Can Be Placed On>"]}}}
```

This is derived from ModDL's answer, however the conversion to 1.13 was sufficiently different that I felt it merited an answer instead of a comment.